# Error C2440: 'return' cannot convert from 'const bool' to 'const bool*'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I have a simple piece of code in a header file here:

```
class MyClass {
public: 
  MyClass();

  inline bool const *getValue() const { return value; }

private:
  bool value;
};
```

Which is giving me the error: 
    `Error C2440: 'return' cannot convert from 'const bool' to 'const bool*'`

However, in another section of the code I'm working on, a similar `*getValue()` function is used to return an array, and it works fine... 
Does anyone know how to make this code legal? Noob here

Thanks!!

Comment: Read about an array's conversion into a pointer to its first element in a C++ book near you.

Comment: "make this code legal" - LOL. make it return zero. or delete all the lines... it will be completely legal. *sigh*. Do you have any functional requirements?

Comment: It would be helpful to read a tutorial on C pointers. E.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Comment: Why so much downmarking? This seems to be a honest question of someone not so much familiar with this language...

Comment: @Kupto Please look at the tooltip that shows up, when you hover over the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Obviously, Mr. Tolkien is 'N00B'. And such error output (even though completely understandable to us) is hard to google or grasp for beginner.

Comment: @Kupto In that case - you are better off by reading C++ books - since you are lacking basic knowledge of the language. We all were beginners, yet, I didn't have such problems, since compiler was explicit in the error message, and there was nothing confusing about it.

Answer (score 2):

The function has return type

```
bool const *
```

while the return value has type `const bool` (the qualifier is added because the method is constant)

```
return value;
```

And there is no explicit conversion from an object of type `const bool` to a pointer of type `bool const *`.

Thus the reason of the error is clear enough.

Maybe you mean

```
bool getValue() const { return value; }
^^^^
```

Take into account that a member function defined in the class definition is by default an inline function.

> However, in another section of the code I'm working on, a similar
>   *getValue() function is used to return an array, and it works fine... Does 
>   anyone know how to make this code legal?

As for arrays then arrays used in expressions are implicitly (with rare exceptions) are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Thus if you have for example a data member that is an array like this

```
int a[N];
```

then this method will be correct

```
int const * getValue() const { return a; }
```

The member function returns pointer to the first element of the array `a`.

Comment: I would add that the OP's code can be made to compile by having the `getValue()` method return type `bool`, i.e. `inline bool getValue() const { return value; }`

Comment: @JamieBullock I already showed how to define the member function.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature says you will return a pointer, but your return statement is returning a bool.  Which did you want to do?

Speculation : What *might* be messing you up is that arrays and pointers are closely related in C / C++. If you have an array of A, that array will convert automatically to a pointer to A. So code that *looks* similar to yours might well work, when the member is an array rather than bool.

Comment: This looks like a comment.

Comment: Could you provide more specific answer to help OP understand what is he doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the keyword `inline` is not necessary.

### Now, there are two things you might want your function to do:

**A)** You want to return the value of the stored variable `value`. This will be accomplished like this.

```
bool getValue() const  
{ return value; }
```

**B)** You want to return constant pointer or constant reference to member variable `value`. This is not a good thing to do, i.e. **DON'T DO THIS**! Because it breaks the encapsulation.

```
const bool * getValue() const  
{ return &value; }
```

---

The option B) might be tempting, because you could use this pointer to look at the variable value at any time, but that is exactly what the getter function should be for. Therefore don't do such thing! Let me know, if the explanation given does not seem to be clear.

Also, you might want to have a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) tutorial on pointers.